# What's with these question related to "sour milk"? Are they on-topic?

Tags: discussion

1. [How to I neutralize the smell of (VERY) spoiled milk](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150254/how-to-i-neutralize-the-smell-of-very-spoiled-milk)
2. [How do I make slightly sour milk palatable again?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150272/how-do-i-make-slightly-sour-milk-palatable-again)

These 2 questions were asked recently. IMO, the answer should be "Don't do such things! Just throw it and buy a new one. These habits are unhealthy and unhygenic". The OPs are "apparently" seeking "some chemical methods" which makes the questions apparently chemistry related. But, I don't think these are full-fledged chemistry questions. Even if it is a chemistry question, it might get closed as the questions are kind of "opinion-based" (as OPs are seeking advice, thus the answers will vary according to the answerer's opinions), ultimately making them off-topic.

Now, the tags [food-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-chemistry), [biochemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) and [smell](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smell) can be appropriate for above questions but the on-topic questions of these tags here starts with "Why...?" or "What causes ...?" because the OPs are seeking for a scientific explanation on something (good examples: [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115219/why-does-lemon-juice-reduce-the-fish-odor-of-sea-food-specifically-fish) and [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/99659/what-causes-the-rotting-fish-smell)).

So, are the said questions on-topic? If yes, why? Is cooking.SE appropriate for that?

Comment: I also believe these questions should be considered off-topic as they are related to personal health. And as you said, Cooking SE would be a better platform to know if your milk is "edible" and if any remedies are present. On the other hand the question you mentioned later should be considered on-topic as they are related to the chemistry behind "food" and can be categories under food chemistry.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Neither question is asking about whether milk is still edible. I think personal medical question is not the best close reason. It is off-topic, I think that is all there is to it.

Comment: Maybe a new close reason would be useful: **"Questions on everyday phenomena must explicitly ask about the chemical principles behind such occurrences, and must not simply be focused on finding a solution to a problem."** or something similar.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes that would be actually the best option for such questions.

Comment: For what it's worth, the second question has been edited, and I think it's on-topic now.

Comment: The 3rd Q from the same author [What happens if you add pure food grade lactic acid to fresh pasteurized milk](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/150750/what-happens-if-you-add-pure-food-grade-lactic-acid-to-fresh-pasteurized-milk)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The amount of "chemistry" involved in both of the questions is rather small. I can understand about people asking for a *scientific explanation* of a phenomenon, but in my opinion, questions like these are better suited at [Lifehacks.SE](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/). They aren't interested in the chemistry but rather how to achieve an aim.

For example: [How do I get rid of sour milk smell from a plastic container](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/18162) seems to be on-topic there.

I don't consider "an acid reacts with a base" to be particularly insightful chemical knowledge, nor do I find that a particularly compelling reason why such questions should be on-topic here. If we were to field questions about literally any acid-base reaction then we would be here for ages.

Comment: (+1) And I would upvote 10 times, if I could, just for your last sentence! At least we are not asked why chemistry is depicted on television as involving colored water and dry ice in Erlenmeyer flasks. I hope it stays that way.

Comment: But …, but …, we're still gonna be here for ages though, aren't we?!

Comment: @EdV I don't want to burst bubbles, (because bubbles are great,) but we have a tag for that: [tag:chemistry-in-fiction].

Comment: @Martin-マーチン A chemistry-in-fiction tag?! Oh, no! I don’t dare look at anything with that tag. I could only watch one episode of Breaking Bad because of that “mercury fulminate” rubbish.

Comment: @EdV You need to develop better suspension of disbelief ;>

Comment: @Mithoron All the Star Trek series were hard enough: I loved the shows, except for cringing every time they mentioned deuterium, dilithium, trilithium, gold-pressed latinum, etc. I have no problem with fiction messing with physics, just not chemistry! ;-)